# creation or copying of file not working if the file path having wild card (*)

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am creating script where i'll find a executable script in path and once its found i'll come two step backward and go to another directory to take a backup but while cd to that directory i'll be using asterisk wildcard in the directory name Cell but /*Cell*/ with wildcard is not accepting while creating new file or copying file etc.I think instead of considering asterisk as wildcard it considering it as directory name itself.

To understand in simple way. i recreated that by just touch command.

Can someone please help me how to overcome this.

## Listing of file working with *Cell*

```
# ls -lrt /usr/WebSphere/AppServer70/profiles/Dmgr01/bin/../config/cells/*Cell*/admin-authz.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 wasadm wasadm 84047 Mar 28 06:14 /usr/WebSphere/AppServer70/profiles/Dmgr01/bin/../config/cells/lmsdqndpv01Cell07/admin-authz.xml`
```

## Creation of file fails with *Cell*

```
`# touch /usr/WebSphere/AppServer70/profiles/Dmgr01/bin/../config/cells/*Cell*/test
touch: cannot touch ‘/usr/WebSphere/AppServer70/profiles/Dmgr01/bin/../config/cells/*Cell*/test’: No such file or directory`
```

## Creation of file working with *lmsdqndpv01Cell07

```
`# touch /usr/WebSphere/AppServer70/profiles/Dmgr01/bin/../config/cells/lmsdqndpv01Cell07/test`
```

## Listing of file working with *Cell*

```
`# ls -lrt /usr/WebSphere/AppServer70/profiles/Dmgr01/bin/../config/cells/*Cell*/test
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 28 07:00 /usr/WebSphere/AppServer70/profiles/Dmgr01/bin/../config/cells/lmsdqndpv01Cell07/test
```

Comment: You cannot use reserved chars for filenames: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words

Comment: Filename is not a problem for me. i am not using reserved chars in file name. My file path have /lmsdqndpv01Cell07/filename in one server and /lmsdqndpv05Cell03/filenname in another server like random names follwed by filename. But in all the server directory will have Cell, thatswhy i am using /*Cell*/ while listing the file. That is working fine. But if try to copy or modify the file with the same its not working. Any way to accomplish this ? Ex - cp /*Cell*/filename /Cell*/filename2

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by below command but wondering if any simple way to do this.

```
for file in $(find $bin/../config/cells/*Cell*/ -name admin-authz.xml) ;
  do
    cp $file "$file"_"$LanID"_consoleaccess_`date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M'`
  done
```

Comment: This is a  less than ideal method...  If you can't simply `for file in $bin/../config/cells/*/admin-authz.xml; do cp ..`, and you need to search for files recursively, consider bash's `globstar` option (search for "globstar" in the man page), or use `find`'s `-exec` option.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
in="your-directory"
out="your-backup-directory"
find "$in" -name "*Cell" -type d -exec cp -r {} "$out" \;
```